# Can I shred empty space on the filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, secure-erase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to shred already removed file on modern filesystem? (randomize free space, journal, tails, … securely)](https://superuser.com/questions/328058/how-to-shred-already-removed-file-on-modern-filesystem-randomize-free-space-j)

One can't securely delete ("shred") a file on journalled filesystems, right?

Is there a *nix utility which will shred all the unused clusters on my disk and its journal, so that all deleted files become unrecoverable?