# How to scramble a directory name as part of a secure erase under Linux?

Tags: linux, privacy, secure-erase, file-shredding, shred

There are many tools available for Linux to securely erase data on a per file basis: [`shred`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils), [`wipe`](http://wipe.sourceforge.net), [`srm`](http://srm.sourceforge.net), ... you name it. Related instructions and advices typically focus on the contents of the files to be erased but rarely on these file's names, that are left untouched for undesired recovery in residual directory entries by most of these tools. One positive exception on non-journalling file systems is `shred`, see below.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

> Imagine that you live in a country that severely penalizes any activity related to Fnords. So you really do not want be caught with an overseen directory entry of a file named
>
> `Frobnicating_Fnords_mini-HOWTO.html`
>
> in your file system even if that file's contents was overwritten 32 times by `srm`. If you use a non-journalling file system, you can use `shred -u ...`, which takes care of that problem by renaming the file several times before unlinking it.
>
> However, `shred` can not be used for directories. So what to do with the directory
>
> `Frobnicating_Fnords_mini-HOWTO_files`
>
> that accompanies the `html` file in this example?

That is the background for my question:

**Is there a tool for Linux—or a shell script fragment that can be used on the command line—that securely scrambles the name of a directory so that it can not be recovered any more on the file system level?**

Please note: This question is not about recurring into a directory to erase a whole directory tree. It is about camouflaging the name of a single directory.

To focus the question: Let's assume that we are using a non-encrypted, non-journalling file system like `Ext2`.

Looking into the [sources of `shred`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shred.c), namely the function `wipename`, it seems that it just does simple renames (`renameatu`) prior unlinking the file. Unfortunately, I was not able to get the desired result by mimicking this method by `mv` and `rename` on the command line. (Why?) See the supplement below for details on that.

Of course, one possible solution would be to just conventionally delete all compromising files and directories, copy the whole file system content to a second file system, securely erase the first one, and optionally copy everything back. But I am looking for a less invasive method, something that you can do quickly as soon as you hear THEIR helicopters...

---

**Warning**

The [man page of `shred`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) states a lag of effectiveness in the case of journalling Ext3 file systems only for the mount option `data=journal`. This is only correct with respect to the erasure of file contents, but not regarding `shred`'s ability to scramble file names: The latter breaks on Ext3 and Ext4 no matter which mode of the `data` mount option is used. The reason is that file names are meta data and always journalled on these file systems. That the file names survive a `shred -u ...` in these cases can easily be verified with the methods shown in the supplement below.

---

**Supplement**

As Patrick Mevzek suggested in his comment, I give here the details of my trial to mimic `shred`'s renaming strategy to scramble a directory name:

First, I set up a (new) image file to hold a test file system and mounted that file system on `/mnt`:

```
rm -f img
truncate -s 3M img
losetup /dev/loop0 img
mke2fs -m 0 -t ext2 /dev/loop0
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/
```

Then, I created the directory `kkkkkkkkkk` in `/mnt` and therein created a regular file named `lllllllllll` with the content `mmmmmmmmmm`. Then I synced:

```
cd /mnt
mkdir kkkkkkkkkk
cd kkkkkkkkkk
echo mmmmmmmmmm > lllllllllll
sync
```

Inspecting the image file (in another directory), all these character patterns were visible:

```
# hexdump -C img | grep kkk
0001c030  d4 03 0a 02 6b 6b 6b 6b  6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 00 00  |....kkkkkkkkkk..|
# hexdump -C img | grep lll
0001f820  6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c 6c  6c 6c 6c 00 00 00 00 00  |lllllllllll.....|
# hexdump -C img | grep mmm
00080400  6d 6d 6d 6d 6d 6d 6d 6d  6d 6d 0a 00 00 00 00 00  |mmmmmmmmmm......|
```

Back in `/mnt/kkkkkkkkkk`, I did a

```
shred -u lllllllllll
```

which yields

```
# hexdump -C img | grep kkk
0001c030  d4 03 0a 02 6b 6b 6b 6b  6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 00 00  |....kkkkkkkkkk..|
# hexdump -C img | grep lll
# hexdump -C img | grep mmm
```

on a subsequent inspection of the image file. Note that the last two commands did not give any output: So `shred` successfully scrambled the content (`mmmmmmmmmm`) and the name (`lllllllllll`) of the regular file.

Now I wanted to overwrite the name of the (now empty) directory `kkkkkkkkkk`. For that I did:

```
cd /mnt
mv kkkkkkkkkk xxxxxxxxxx
sync
```

yielding

```
# hexdump -C img | grep kkk
0001c030  14 00 0a 02 6b 6b 6b 6b  6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 6b 00 00  |....kkkkkkkkkk..|
# hexdump -C img | grep xxx
0001c040  0c 00 00 00 c0 03 0a 02  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  |........xxxxxxxx|
```

Instead, I desired to get no output from `grep kkk`. Obviously, the `mv` made a new directory entry for the renamed directory `xxxxxxxxxx` rather than reusing the old slot, which in consequence still holds the old name `kkkkkkkkkk`.

I also tried `rename(1)`, with a similar result: The old directory name survived.

Comment: "I was not able to get the desired result by mimicking this method by mv and rename on the command line. " What did you do exactly as commands and how the results were different from what you expected?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Thank you for your hint. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: If you hear their helicopters a hammer might be the quickest way and if they are using a helicopter even than they might be willing to spend the money. Use an encrypted volume and you don't have the issue you're constructing.

Comment: For ext2 and later filesystems, maybe look at command `clri` in `debug2fs`, the man page says for it: Clear the contents of the inode filespec.    Or also `modify_inode` and `set_inode_field`. And finally `zap_block`.

Comment: You are right, @Seth, with both of your points: Mechanical destruction as a last resort is pretty adequate for this exemplary immanent helicopter thread, and using encrypted partitions---a very good advice in this context---prevents this problem completely. However, both attempts do not actually work on a per file basis: In fact, notwithstanding the artificial nature of my example, the need to get rid of a compromising directory name on a non-encrypted file system does not seem to be very unrealistic.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: The `debug2fs` tools are a very good hint for `ExtX` file systems. However, `crli`, `modify_inode`, and `set_inode_field` can not be used in this case, because file and directory names are not stored in the inodes but in the directory structure. But there, `zap_block`, as you suggested, is perfect for this need. Thank you for this tip. Nevertheless, this attempt requires intimate knowledge about the ExtX data structures and is heavily error prone. So, what I had in mind was something like `shred++` or `wipe2` that handles the problem in a more general and secure way.

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this in a fast manner with big volumes. The "easy" solution to your problem is [overwriting free disk space](https://superuser.com/questions/19326/how-to-wipe-free-disk-space-in-linux). Which can be done in a number of ways. You might still be left with "problematic" names depending on your setup you'd have to make sure to have a root node and follow up that are "unproblematic" but again the simplest solution is to use an encrypted volume if you know you're handling such dangerous files. Erase the volume if you're "in danger" and you're done.